# Merge / concatenate an array of maps into one map in spark SQL with built-ins

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Consider the following DataFrame. Here I want the array of maps merged into one map without using UDFs.

```
+---+------------------------------------+
|id |greek                               |
+---+------------------------------------+
|1  |[{alpha -> beta}, {gamma -> delta}] |
|2  |[{epsilon -> zeta}, {etha -> theta}]|
+---+------------------------------------+
```

I think I've tried *all* the mapping funcions in the [pyspark 3 docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql.html#functions). I thought I'd be able to do `map_from_entries`, but it just throws an exception where it says it requires maps and not an array of maps?

Although I'm aware that this is easily done using UDFs, I find it hard to believe that there are no easier way?

#### Runnable python code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .getOrCreate()
)

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, [{"alpha": "beta"}, {"gamma": "delta"}]),
    (2, [{"epsilon": "zeta"}, {"etha": "theta"}])
],
    schema=["id", "greek"]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another version using high-order functions:

```py
map_schema = df.selectExpr('greek[0]').dtypes[0][1]

expr = "REDUCE(greek, cast(map() as {schema}), (acc, el) -> map_concat(acc, el))".format(schema=map_schema)
df = df.withColumn("Concated", F.expr(expr))
```

Output:

```
+---+------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|id |greek                               |Concated                        |
+---+------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|1  |[{alpha -> beta}, {gamma -> delta}] |{alpha -> beta, gamma -> delta} |
|2  |[{epsilon -> zeta}, {etha -> theta}]|{epsilon -> zeta, etha -> theta}|
+---+------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured one approach that would use the `aggregate` built-in:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

## Aggregate needs a column with the array to be iterated,
## an initial value and a merge function.

## For the initial value, we need an empty map with corresponding map schema 
## which evaluates to (map<string,string>) in this case

map_schema = df.selectExpr('greek[0]').dtypes[0][1]
## F.create_map() creates a 'map<null,null>' type.
empty_map = F.create_map().cast(map_schema)

df.withColumn("Concated",
              F.aggregate(
                # Values to iterate
                col=F.col("greek"),
                # Initial value
                initialValue=empty_map,
                merge = lambda acc, el: F.map_concat(acc, el)
              )
)
```

### Edit

As pointed out by @kafels, the issue about duplicates should be addressed. According to the [spark configuration docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) it would throw an exception if the keys are duplicate. To avoid this, and let the last key win, set the following spark sql option:

```
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.mapKeyDedupPolicy', 'LAST_WIN')
```

Comment: you can try using `F.create_map().cast('map<string,string>')` as `initialValue` and do it without slicing

Comment: Awesome, @mck. If you know any clean way of getting the map schema/type from the column, then that would be awesome!

Comment: `df.selectExpr('greek[0]').dtypes[0][1]`

Comment: Remember to set `spark.conf.set('spark.sql.mapKeyDedupPolicy', 'LAST_WIN')` option if you want merge duplicate keys

Answer (score 1):

My approach is explode the parent list, explode the keys, explode the values, then merge them all together

```py
(df
    .withColumn('g', F.explode('greek'))
    .withColumn('k', F.explode(F.map_keys('g')))
    .withColumn('v', F.explode(F.map_values('g')))
    .groupBy('id')
    .agg(
        F.collect_list('k').alias('key'),
        F.collect_list('v').alias('value')
    )
    .withColumn('single_map', (F.map_from_arrays('key', 'value')))
    .show(10, False)
)

# +---+---------------+-------------+--------------------------------+
# |id |key            |value        |single_map                      |
# +---+---------------+-------------+--------------------------------+
# |1  |[alpha, gamma] |[beta, delta]|{alpha -> beta, gamma -> delta} |
# |2  |[epsilon, etha]|[zeta, theta]|{epsilon -> zeta, etha -> theta}|
# +---+---------------+-------------+--------------------------------+
```